# Why mathematicians\logicians try to establish totally mechanical frameworks, in the first place?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

As much as I know, at least for the past 200 years mathematicians\logicians are doing their best in order to reduce their works into syntax (into some totally mechanical frameworks) accoding to some agreements.

As I get it, in order to answer this question (or even to understand enything of what I wirte here) at least some agreed rules are related to some objects. If so, the vary notion of agreement (even if done between one to itself) can't totally avoid semantics, in order to be undersood.

So why mathematicians\logicians try to establish totally mechanical frameworks, in the first place?

Comment: Reliability. The more mechanical each step is made the more likely it is that there will be no disagreement on the outcome when the deduction or calculation is inspected step by step. The semantics is outsourced to the generation of axioms and mechanical rules, and there is a fair amount of disagreements surrounding those. But once that is sorted out, or set aside for the sake, at least we can be fairly confident that the rest will not produce any more disagreements. Compare to just about every other human discourse, where such mechanization is *not* done.

Comment: Leibniz once answered in a private letter: *It is true that in the past I planned a new way of calculating suitable for matters which have nothing in common with mathematics, and if this kind of logic were put into practice... the lesser minds which had application and good will could, if not accompany the greatest minds, then at least follow them... But I do not know if I will ever be in a position to carry out such a project, which requires more than one hand; and it even seems that mankind is still not mature enough to lay claim to the advantages which this method could provide...*

Comment: It also helps computerize mathematics. imo, we still haven't leveraged the tremendous computing power we have towards mathematics. We have some automatic theorem proving and proof assistants. But these have limited success. Most mathematics isn't done using pure symbolic format, so it's tough to put them into computers.

Comment: In additional to practical reasons like reliability and removal of disagreement, the very fact that mathematics seems so "susceptible" to being expressed in syntactical terms might be taken as some kind of philosophically important clue to what separates mathematics from other types of symbolic expression like natural language, what is its essential nature so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

The object of that program is to boil out of the language we use for quantitative reasoning any vestiges of cultural context, spoken language, human behavior and so on, so that which remains is useful no matter where you live, what language you speak, which religion you believe in or what political party you are a member of.

The physicist Stephen Weinberg's analogy for this is the process by which raw ore is refined into metal, and the resulting slag is discarded.

Comment: Can such a mechanic program quantify usefulness without boil out its users?

Comment: Of course. It quantifies usefulness by furnishing accurate numerical answers to equations.